# Update column value only after @ sign

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have a column named as `EMAIL` in my table which *lets say* has users' Email:

```
user123@hotmail.com
user145@yahoo.com
```

Now, the requirement is to update only domain part of the email of users. So I need to update `Email` column value which is after `@` sign.

For above data, the users' email should look like this way after update:

```
user123@gmail.com
user145@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to update every email address to have a Gmail domain, you can use an `UPDATE` statement without a `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET EMAIL = LEFT(EMAIL, CHARINDEX('@', EMAIL)-1) + '@' + 'gmail.com'
```

This could also be written as:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET EMAIL = LEFT(EMAIL, CHARINDEX('@', EMAIL)) + 'gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way with [`SUBSTRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187748.aspx)

```
UPDATE TableName SET Email = SUBSTRING(Email, 1, CHARINDEX('@', Email)) + 'gmail.com'
```

---

Execution with given sample data:

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE (Id INT, Email VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @Employee (Id, Email) VALUES
(1, 'user123@hotmail.com'), (2, 'user145@yahoo.com');

UPDATE @Employee SET Email = SUBSTRING(Email, 1, CHARINDEX('@', Email)) + 'gmail.com'

--SELECT * FROM @Employee
```

Comment: It has removed all characters before '@' sign.

Comment: @user55: I verified in [fiddler](http://rextester.com/WQLVDT91426) too, its working.

Comment: In my case, it generated wrong results. i think i made  some mistake while executing this query. Anyhow thanks buddy for your concern.